# Create Image Button in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: css, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

How can i create  Image Button in Oracle Apex 5 ? I am using **Universal Theme** in my application.

I have set **Button Attributes** as below.

[image: Button Attributes]

But it display like this.

[image: display]

**UPDATE**

After using `style="background-image:url(#APP_IMAGES#holidays.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;"` in **Button Attributes** field, image display like this.

[image: updated_img]

Instead of full image it displays cropped image.

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button templates of the Universal Theme in APEX 5.0 are CSS icons only. If you need an image button for just a small number of buttons, use the "Text" button template and enter

```
<img src="#APP_IMAGES#holidays.png">
```

into the "Label" attribute of your button. If you want to have your own Image button template, go to Shared Components -> Templates and copy the existing "Icon and Text" button template and name it "Image and Text" and use the following HTML markup

```
<button class="t-Button t-Button--icon #BUTTON_CSS_CLASSES#" #BUTTON_ATTRIBUTES# onclick="#JAVASCRIPT#" type="button" id="#BUTTON_ID#"><img src="#ICON_CSS_CLASSES#"><span class="t-Button-label">#LABEL#</span></button>
```

Use the "Icon CSS Classes" attribute of your button to specify the image.

Hope that helps
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to define the path to an image in a field used for specifying a CSS class. Either create a CSS class that defines your image and use that, or reference the image directly in the 'Button Attributes' field.

e.g...

```
.holidayButton {
  background-image:url(#APP_IMAGES#holidays.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

or

`style="background-image:url(#APP_IMAGES#holidays.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;"`

You probably want to read up on CSS and have a play with some of the attributes in your developer tools whilst running your application in order to fine tune things. The MDN site is an excellent resource.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: Your solution worked. But still have a issue. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Try `style="background-image:url(#APP_IMAGES#holidays.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain"`. I'm no CSS expert I'm afraid! Try playing around with the styles in your browser using the developer tools. This is essential for any web application developer.